# GroupBy Date and Name

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataset and would like to group by Name and Month and Year. I would like to calculate how many times the name appears in every month of the year:

```
Date                       Name   
2019-11-10 18:59:31+00:00  A      
2020-11-07 18:59:31+00:00  A      
2021-05-10 18:59:31+00:00  B      
2020-11-09 18:59:31+00:00  C      
2021-05-01 18:59:31+00:00  B      
2020-12-10 18:59:31+00:00  C      
2019-12-10 18:59:31+00:00  B
```

I do not know how exactly the result would be, but I expect something similar to this so I can then make a graph:

```
2019-11 A 1
2020-11 A 1
2021-05 B 2
2020-11 C 1
2020-12 C 1
2019-12 B 1
```

I have tried the following method:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='1M')).groupby('Name').count()
```

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: Is the `Date` column a `datetime` dtype? I think your code should work if before setting it as index you set `Date` to datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'),'Name'])['Name'].count().rename('count').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      Date Name  count
0  2019-11    A      1
1  2019-12    B      1
2  2020-11    A      1
3  2020-11    C      1
4  2020-12    C      1
5  2021-05    B      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is Date the first column to the DataFrame, it should be

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='1M')).groupby('Name').count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting `Date` to year/month using `to_period('M')`:

```
df.groupby([df.Date.dt.to_period('M'),df.Name]).agg(count = ('Date','count')).reset_index()
```

Result is:

```
      Date Name  count
0  2019-11    A      1
1  2019-12    B      1
2  2020-11    A      1
3  2020-11    C      1
4  2020-12    C      1
5  2021-05    B      2
```